# Autofac 1.3.2 dynamic instantiation error with .NET 3.0

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac

```
public class A
{
  Func<B> _b;

  public A(Func<B> b) { _b = b; }

  public void M()
  {
      var b = _b();
      b.DoSomething();
  }
}`
```

When I resolve it throws error, is it theoretically possible to dynamic instantiate with old version of Autofac? and if not what can be solution?

Comment: Please show the full exception

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'Autofac.DependencyResolutionException' occurred in Autofac.dll

Additional information: The component 'autofac.net3._0.A' has no resolvable constructors. Unsuitable constructors included:

Void .ctor(autofac.net3._0.Func`1[autofac.net3._0.B]): parameter 'b' of type 'autofac.net3._0.Func`1[autofac.net3._0.B]' is not resolvable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old version of Autofac doesn't have auto-generated factories features. You have to use the `RegisterGeneratedFactory` method to register a factory.

ie :

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Register<A>().As<A>();
builder.Register<B>().As<B>();

builder.RegisterGeneratedFactory<Func<B>>();

var container = builder.Build();

container.Resolve<A>().M();
```

The following link : [Generate generic factories with Autofac](http://peterspattern.com/generate-generic-factories-with-autofac/) explain how to create a `RegisterGeneratedFactoryFromOpenType` extension method which should allow you to register a generic `Func<T>` factory.

Answer (score 0):

No.
Auto-Generated Factories are available sinse the 2.x version.

Possible solution:

```
public class A
{
  ILifetimeScope  _scope;

  public A(ILifetimeScope scope) { _scope = scope; }

  public void M()
  {
      var b = _scope.Resolve<B>();
      b.DoSomething();
  }
}`
```